# How to insert multiple rows in MySQL with a where clause

Tags: python, mysql, database, insert, rows

I'm making a server for an online merch and I need to store the log of the change in the tables but I cannot use triggers and need to store multiple at a time but it must be a general function since I don't know how many records must be made.

I tried getting the number of records in a variable and executing the query multiple times with a for but the number the query doesn't work.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO InputProva(CODODL, CODART, QTAPRO, COMMES) SELECT CODODL, CODART, QTAPRO, COMMES FROM InputServer WHERE FLELAB = 'N'; "
sql2="UPDATE InputServer SET FLELAB = 'S' WHERE FLELAB = 'N'"
i=0
num = system.db.runQuery("SELECT COUNT SELECT * FROM InputServer WHERE COMMES = 'S'")

for i in num :
    system.db.runUpdateQuery(sql)
    system.db.runUpdateQuery(sql2)
```

I need to be able to execute the query but when I try to run it it says "num is not a valid range".

Comment: try to replace `"SELECT COUNT SELECT * FROM InputServer WHERE COMMES = 'S'"` with `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM InputServer WHERE COMMES = 'S'"`?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of edits in your code and it should be good to run

`num = system.db.runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM InputServer WHERE COMMES = 'S'")`

`for i in range(num) :
    system.db.runUpdateQuery(sql)
    system.db.runUpdateQuery(sql2)`